# How can I identify Emulator configuration is correct or it has incorrect configuration

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am developing Phonegap application for that I followed installation guide and its working well.

When I start Emulator with AVD Manager its starting without any error but I am not getting any Emulator screen.

What could be the issue. How can I know configuration is correct or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android AVD emulators take a lot of time to load and start. To load them fast you could configure them to use Host GPU instead of save snapshot while creating the virtual device, or you can try genymotion [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/), for personal use its free.